# How to parse json nested array

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to fetch data from json array using java gson library following is the json string to parse

```
{
    'result': 'success',
    'value': {
        'count': 201671,
        'data': [
            {
                'id': '14906999986115',
                'address': '848E3rdSt',
                'zipcode': '90001',
                'name': 'montreras',
                'state': 'CA',
                'city': 'LosAngeles'
            },
            {
                'id': '14906999999454',
                'address': '92E75thSt',
                'zipcode': '90001',
                'name': 'AD.Graves',
                'state': 'CA',
                'city': 'LosAngeles'
            },
            {
                'id': '14906999997706',
                'address': '1320E83rdSt',
                'zipcode': '90001',
                'name': 'A.Irvin',
                'state': 'CA',
                'city': 'LcopAngeles'
            },
            {
                'id': '14906999982106',
                'address': '14081/2E82ndSt',
                'zipcode': '90001',
                'name': 'AdmoniaHurt',
                'state': 'CA',
                'city': 'LosAngeles'
            },
            {
                'id': '14906999996091',
                'address': '20E77thSt',
                'zipcode': '90001',
                'name': 'AdolphA.,
                'state': 'CA',
                'city': 'LosAngeles'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How to get data from data array in above string?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code? Also, a reasonably-formatted version of the JSON wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this given you json is valid and has a similar structure

```
jsonStr = "your json string here";

Result result = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, Result.class)

class Result{
 public String result;
 public Value value;
}

class Value{
 public int count
 public ArrayList<Data> data;
}

class Data{
 public String id;
 public String address;
 public String zipcode;
 public String name;
 public String state;
 public String city;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you know which data structures to expect, like a "value" object having some properties in your example above.
Read the gson documentation on deserialization and you're done: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Primitives-Examples